# Latex table header column aligning with rows below

Tags: tables, columns

I would like to have the column values in my latex table aligned. As you can see in the table below, the header columns from the 6th column onwards are not aligned with the row values below.

I was hoping someone could help me align the header column so that they mive
a bit to the left, especially for columns 6,7, 9 and 10!

[image]

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Shapefile movement times (in \textit{seconds}) }
\label{tab:maskingencryptiontimes}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccrrrrrrrr}
\headrow


\multicolumn{1}{c}{Filename} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Size \\ (Kb)\end{tabular}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Points} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Neutral \\    \textit{w/o SM}~~~~ \textit{w/ SM} \end{tabular} }                  
& \multicolumn{3}{r}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Forward \\ \textit{1 lev}~~~~ \textit{2 lev}~~ \textit{3 lev} \end{tabular} }               
& \multicolumn{3}{r}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Backward \\ \textit{1 lev}~~~~ \textit{2 lev}~~ \textit{3 lev}  \end{tabular} } \\
Belgium-points.zip & 363 & 13,427 & 1.37 & 30.52 & 0.63 & 1.32 & 2.39 & 0.36 & 0.46 & 0.57 \\


\hiderowcolors
\hline  % Please only put a hline at the end of the table
\end{tabular}
   
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

I also want the (grey background) colouring of the rows to start at the header level and alternate thereafter. The first two rows - merged into one should be coloured as one, the next one should be uncoloured (white background) and then the next one should be coloured. I have few more rows after that. I have attached an image in the post. The areas enclosed by the blue rectangle should be colored in grey - basically the exact opposite of what we have now. The colouring should be the same as how F. Pantigny has shown in his solution output. Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document which we can test as it is. It seems that you have problems with of `multicolumn` cells which content is wider than natural widths od spanned columns, Consequently last column width is increased.

Answer (score 2):

- Missed is MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem.
- Due to missed MWE your page layout is unknown, so it may happens that table is to wide that can be fit on page
- So, it is not entirely clear why you use `threeparttable` (Your code fragment doesn't contain any table note), what is your problem and what you are after.

**EDIT:**

- Apparently original question was not complete (consequently partly misleading).
- Additional demands regarding coloring rows can be using original answer simple to fulfil by adding option `row{odd[3-Z]} = {gray!30}` to table preamble (see MWE below).
- So, now I guessing, that you probably looking for something like this:

[image]

For this table I use `tabularray` package with libraries `booktabs` and `siunitx`, split column headers into two rows
column, where n the first column are multicolumn cells, in the second one are headers of each column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
\begin{talltblr}[
caption={Shapefile movement times (in \textit{seconds})},
  label={tab:maskingencryptiontimes}
                ]{colsep = 3pt,
                  colspec = {l c 
                                  X[c, si={table-format=2.3}]
                             *{8}{X[c, si={table-format=2.2}]} 
                            },
                  cell{1}{1-3} = {r=2}{},
                  cell{2}{4-Z} = {font=\itshape},
                  row{1}  = {guard, font=\footnotesize\bfseries},
                  row{2}  = {guard, font=\footnotesize}, 
                  row{odd[3-Z]} = {gray!30} % added for "zebra" coloring of table
                  }
    \toprule
Filename
    &   {Size\\ (Kb)}
        &   Points
            &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Neutral
                &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Forward
                        &   &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Backward
                                        &   &           \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-8}
    \cmidrule[lr]{9-11}
    &   &   &   w/o SM
                &   w/ SM
                    &   1 lev
                        &   2 lev
                            &   3 lev
                                &   1 lev
                                    &   2 lev
                                        &   3 lev     \\
    \midrule
Belgium-points.zip 
    & 363 
        & 13,427 
            & 1.37 
                & 30.52 
                    & 0.63 
                        & 1.32 
                            & 2.39 
                                & 0.36 
                                    & 0.46 
                                        & 0.57      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses multirow with a normal tabular.  I coudn't find two of your macros.

The easiest way ot align headers with the columns is to use them.  At first I tried to center all the headers, then realized than in most cases it didn't matter.

Lastly, you are using up a lot of width on the filenames.  I would try abreviations with table notes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{showframe}% show margins
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{Shapefile movement times (in \textit{seconds}) }
\label{tab:maskingencryptiontimes}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lccrrrrrrrr}
%\headrow% could not find in sty files
\multirow{2}{*}{Filename} 
  & Size
  & \multirow{2}{*}{Points} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Neutral}            
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Forward}               
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Backward}
\\
  & (Kb)
  &
  & \textit{w/o SM} & \textit{w/ SM}% widest row
  & \textit{1 lev} & \textit{2 lev} & \textit{3 lev}
  & \textit{1 lev} & \textit{2 lev} & \textit{3 lev}
\\
  Belgium-points.zip & 363 & 13,427 & 1.37 & 30.52 & 0.63 & 1.32 & 2.39 & 0.36 & 0.46 & 0.57 \\
%\hiderowcolors% could not find in sty files
\hline  % Please only put a hline at the end of the table
\end{tabular}
   
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yours is the most simple solution. It works.
I just want the colouring of the rows to start at the header level and alternate thereafter. The first two rows - merged into one should be coloured, the next one should be uncoloured and then the next one should be coloured.  I have attached an image in the initial post.

Comment: The colouring should be the same as how F. Pantigny has shown in his solution output below. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

You won't see thin white lines in the colored panels, whatever PDF viewer you use...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\caption{Shapefile movement times (in \textit{seconds})}

\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lcc*{8}{X[c]}}
\CodeBefore
\rowcolor{gray!30}{1,2}
\Body
\toprule
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{Filename}
    & \Block{2-1}{Size\\ (Kb)}
        & \Block{2-1}{Points}
            &  \Block{1-2}{Neutral}
                &   & \Block{1-3}{Forward}
                        &   &   & \Block{1-3}{Backward} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    \cmidrule(lr){9-11}
\RowStyle{\footnotesize}
    &   &   &   w/o SM
                &   w/ SM
                    &   1 lev
                        &   2 lev
                            &   3 lev
                                &   1 lev
                                    &   2 lev
                                        &   3 lev     \\
    \midrule
Belgium-points.zip 
    & 363 
        & 13,427 
            & 1.37 
                & 30.52 
                    & 0.63 
                        & 1.32 
                            & 2.39 
                                & 0.36 
                                    & 0.46 
                                        & 0.57      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}    

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]